# Any design patterns for handling the following case in Java?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java & its design patterns, I have a scenario like this:

Method 1 calls Method 2.

Method 2 looks like the following:

```
public String createUser(String username, String password) {
    someApi.do(config -> {
        //code here with respect to someApi.
    });
}
```

now the trick is I need to return the value to caller which is method 1. If there are no exceptions then that is fine. However the code block inside `do` can throw exception, which will be handled in a separate listener class like this:

```
public class TestListener implements SomeApiListener {
    @Override
    public void exception(Throwable cause) {

    }
}
```

Now how should I send back the exception to method 1 from this listener? I'm really confused.

Comment: Normally you pass back an Exception by throwing it (or a wrapping exception) and catching it.

Comment: Well, which is method one ?

Comment: There is clearly a problem if your listener is where the Exception is handle. There is no return statement so your `Throwable` are simply hidden. Please show us a [mcve] to see exactly how this is design. I might be wrong

Comment: What is `someApi`? You can tell us, it's unlikely to be secret.

Comment: It sounds a bit like a Future http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: @MauricePerry What sounds like `Future`?

Comment: i think it's simple a `Callback` pattern where an anonymous inner class (SomeApiListener) can be passed to `createUser()`  i have posted an answer

Comment: That's a lot of guess for the moment, just wait the return of the Je... I mean of the OP. Ge disappeared to quickly.

Comment: @AxelH I hate when people ask questions and leave out information as "irrelevant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not clear what that API do, where the listener is assigned, and what other methods it has, like if there is also `onSuccess()` ?

what i got from this, is that, you are dealing with `async` call, which usually do not return a value directly, it deals with a `CallBack` which in your case is `SomeApiListener`

So, ... I would make `createUser()` receives extra arg, `SomeApiListener`, pass the listener as anonymous inner class (with implementation) when calling the method (from caller).

ex,

```
public String createUser(String username, String password, SomeApiListener listener) {

    someApi.do(config -> {
        //code here with respect to someApi.

        //somewhere here you are creating a TestListener ?, 
        //well... don't, and use the one passed from caller (listener)
    });
}
```

Caller part will look like this:

```
public void method1(){
    //..some code ...

    createUser(username, password, new SomeApiListener(){

        @Override
        public void exception(Throwable cause) {
            //handle exception...
        }

        @Override
        public void success(Response response) {
            //handle response ...
        }
    });
}
```

**Note:** you can still pass `TetstListern`, if you want, in that case you will have to have a physical class (local class) defined and instantiated, the `anonymous-inner-class` is somehow a shortcut for that, you don't create a local class, just pass it as an arg.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not in any simple way. I'd expect the documentation for your `someApi` to demonstrate some common use cases, with exception handling included. If you're combining different ways of programming ("normal" java & functional programming), you can get into tricky situations.

Based on the information you've given, a clumsy solution could look something like this (code obviously not fit for compilation):

```
public class MyClass implements SomeApiListener {
    private Throwable e;
    public void exception(Throwable cause) {
        e = cause;
    }

    public void method1() {
        createUser("foo", "bar");
        if(e != null) {
            // Exception was thrown, do something with it
        }
    }
}
```

However this is in no way a recommendation. It's clumsy, hacky and bad in every way. A better solution would involve not trying to send the exception back to `method1`, but instead to modify your code to work in the way that `someApi` expects.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your design on how to handle exceptions. Normally, if the method 2 is an utility method then throw the exception back to method 1 and let it handle the exception. Else, if method 2 understands the use case for which it is called then handle the exception there. There are no hard and fast rules, but keep the utility classes clean and send the exception back to the caller so that caller can handle it.